# Did Bertrand Russell leave the Second International Congress of Mathematicians to read Giuseppe Peano's Formulario?

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, mathematical-logic

The [Wikipedia page on Giuseppe Peano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano) claims the following:

> At the conference Peano met Bertrand Russell and gave him a copy of
>   Formulario. Russell was so struck by Peano's innovative logical
>   symbols that he left the conference and returned home to study Peano's
>   text.

However, the claim is unreferenced. Did Bertrand Russell leave the Second International Congress of Mathematicians to read Giuseppe Peano's [Formulario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulario_mathematico), or is that just some myth?

*Ray Monk, ‘Russell, Bertrand Arthur William, third Earl Russell (1872–1970)’, Oxford Dictionary of National Biography, Oxford University Press, 2004; online edn, May 2014 (http://www.oxforddnb.com/view/article/35875, accessed 5 Nov 2014)* does not mention this premature departure:

> At Paris, Russell met the Italian mathematician Giuseppe Peano, the
>   head of a movement whose ultimate goal was to construct a single
>   axiomatic system upon which the whole of mathematics could be founded.
>   In pursuit of this aim Peano had invented a special symbolism which he
>   used to construct a system of mathematical logic, at the heart of
>   which is the now-familiar notion of a ‘propositional function’. Using
>   this system, Peano and his colleagues had shown that arithmetic could
>   be founded on a single elegant formal theory which used only three
>   basic ideas (zero, number, and successor) and five initial axioms.
>   Inspired by his meeting with Peano and his study of Peano's work,
>   Russell returned from Paris with an almost ecstatic conviction that he
>   knew the way ahead: if he could show that all mathematical notions
>   were fundamentally arithmetical and that Peano's system was
>   fundamentally a system of logic, then he would have succeeded in his
>   stated aim of demonstrating that mathematics was logic. For this the
>   crucial step would be to show that Peano's axioms could be founded
>   upon a system of logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found in Hubert Kennedy, *Twelve Articles on Giuseppe Peano* (2002) : **[What Russell learned from Peano](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093891001)**, from *Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic* (1983) the following:

> The evidence comes from Russell himself in, among other places, the description of the International Congress of Philosophy in Paris, 1900, in his *Autobiography* (p.217–219):
>
> > The Congress was a turning point in my intellectual life, because I there met Peano. I already knew him by name and had seen some of his work, but had not taken the trouble to master his notation. [...] As the days went by, I decided that this must be owing to his mathematical logic.
> >
> > I therefore got him to give me all his works, and *as soon as the Congress was over* I retired to Fernhurst to study quietly every word written by him and his disciples [emphasis added].